# Django. Get saving values in overrided save method for admin form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Have an admin form with overrided save method:

```
*models.py
class Banners(models.Model):
    <...>
    pages = models.ManyToManyField(Page, verbose_name='Pages', blank=True)

*forms.py
class BannerAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BannerAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['pages'].queryset = Page.objects.filter(publisher_is_draft=1)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
        banner = super(BannerAdminForm, self).save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)

        for c in banner.pages.all():
            print c

        if commit:
            banner.save()
        return banner

    class Meta:
        model = Banners
```

I overrided *save()* method because i want to intercept **pages** that will be added to **banners**, and add some extra **pages** depending of what **pages** was chosen by user. So I need to catch what pages object was chosen... But code **for c in banner.pages.all():** returns me the already existed pages in banner, not the new ones.
If there some way to catch new values before i will *save()* the form ?

And the second question - if comes some new pages and deleted some old ones at the same time... is there will be the same mechanism to catch all that data ?

Comment: You mean you want to intercept the pages that the user sends to the *same form that you are saving*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the pages selected from the form's `cleaned_data`.

```
self.cleaned_data['pages']
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry - forget for that method.
It all fine now, but... I have a one little question: **cleaned_data['pages']** returns a *QuerySet*... and I can't exacly appen this list with some new *pages* from DB... So i mannualy save new pages after performing *save()* method... But maybe there is more ellegant decision ?

Comment: I mean **cleaned_data['pages']** returns a *QuerySet object*... is there some way to add additional QuerySet to this one ?
All that i found - *.add()*, etc. did not work

Comment: You might be able to try converting the queryset to a list with `cleaned_data['pages'] = list(cleaned_data['pages'])`. Then you could add and remove items from the list before saving. However, I haven't tested this to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for all your help ! My last question i solve by override the **cleaned_data['pages']**:

`all_pages = []`
`for page in self.cleaned_data['pages']:`
`all_pages.append(page.id)`            `all_pages.append(Page.objects.get(publisher_public_id=page.id).id)`
`self.cleaned_data['pages'] = Page.objects.filter(id__in=all_pages)`